# What are the top statistic conferences to follow for applications in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, conferences

What are the top statistic conferences to follow for applications in machine learning?

I just had a discussion, regarding that some of the machine learning jargon and buzzwords are not really sound for a top level statistician. So instead of machine learning conferences I would like to follow conferences on statistics (perhaps also journals) for possible applications in machine learning.

Perhaps someone could give me a short list of conferences were I could start searching?

Comment: I'd recommend expanding this to include journals.  :)  In CS, conferences seem to dominate relative to journals, in statistics it tends to be the other way around.  I'd also recommend making this "community wiki", as it's somewhat open subjective.  One person may think that AOS or AOAS is both "top" and "statistical", while another may say that KDD or NIPS is the top for potential applications and theory.

Comment: (Continued) What's more, opinions may vary based on geography.  Although papers are important, connections at conferences matter, too.  Outside of the US, ECML or PAKDD may be more appropriate for reasons of not only the quality of presentations, but the fact that the presenter shares some proximity and may even be able to collaborate under certain data sharing or grant sharing protocols that are affected by geography.  I don't raise this issue to quibble; I'm in the US, and am merely pointing out that sometimes we are ignorant of things elsewhere.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Joint Statistical Meetings are large annual statistical conferences.  To quote their site,

> "JSM (the Joint Statistical Meetings) is the largest gathering of
>   statisticians held in North America. It is held jointly with the
>   American Statistical Association, the International Biometric Society
>   (ENAR and WNAR), the Institute of Mathematical Statistics, the
>   Statistical Society of Canada, and the International Chinese
>   Statistical Association, and the International Indian Statistical
>   Association"

If you search "machine learning" in their 2011 program, you get [68 hits](http://www.amstat.org/meetings/jsm/2011/onlineprogram/KeywordSearchResults.cfm).

Two other annual conferences are the meeting of the [Eastern North American Region](http://www.enar.org/meetings.cfm#meetings) (ENAR) of the International Biometric Society and the meeting of its western counterpart [WNAR](http://www.wnar.org/).  Talks, posters, and sessions on machine learning have become a larger presence at these conferences over the last decade (you can find past years' programs in the links above -- the links to the actual programs weren't working for me this morning, however).